# CarouselView-Xamarin Forms: Data is not getting displayed

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to display data using carousel view in my forms application. I am not sure what am I missing but data is not getting populated, I have followed almost all available samples but still I have not found any success. Please help me get out of this problem:

I am using the following code in my xaml file:

```
<forms:CarouselView x:Name="listview" ItemsSource="postIdList" HeightRequest="200" Margin="5">
                    <forms:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentPage >
                                <StackLayout >
                                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" FontSize="20" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ContentPage>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </forms:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                </forms:CarouselView>
```

And I am trying to populate the data in the following manner in .cs file:

```
List<string> postIdList = new List<string>
{
 "Carousel", "Carousel", "carousel"
};

listview.ItemsSource = postIdList;
```

If I give a background colour for carousal view I am able to see that colour, but text is not getting displayed.
Please let me know my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In case of a ListView, you need an ObservableCollection instead of a List. Switch it around and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

On your XAML you are defining a `<ContentPage>` inside the `<Datatemplate>`. Replace the `<ContentPage>` with a `<ViewCell>` or a `<Grid>`

[Here](https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/) is a great example on how to use it, you need to keep in mind that CarouselView work like a ListView, it need to have a Datatemplate.

Comment: I updated it with a link so you can have a more robust view on how to achieve it!

Comment: I am trying this in xamarin studio and not in visual studio.. will that make  a difference?

Comment: No, its actually the same code, i'm not a XAML fan, but maybe you need to add the CarouselView namespace?